# Possible darts scores and probability thereof

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

As an intellectual exercise only, I am attempting to solve the following: 
by throwing 3 darts at a standard dartboard, it is possible to score a maximum of 180 (3 x treble 20), and a minimum of zero (all darts miss the scoring area).
1. Which total scores within this range are not possible to achieve? (eg 179)
2. For each of the possible scores, how many ways are there to achieve that score? (eg a total of 5 could be
0, 0, 5, or
0, 3, 2, or
0, treble 1, double 1, or
0, 1, double 2

etc etc)

Remember that we are looking at combinations, not permutations, since the order of the 3 darts is irrelevant.

I am working on an Excel solution to this at present and would be interested to see if anyone else has a solution to compare with what I hope will be my solution.

Regards

Comment: How are you modeling the probability of each dart going into each area? Two variable uniform?

Comment: I am not considering the probability of any dart htting any part of the board. It is simply an exercise to work out how many combinations of the 3 darts there are for any particular score. Just curious, and also set myself the challenge since I am now retired and like to keep my brain active!

Comment: Eg score of 1 has only one possibilty. Score of 12 has many combinations of singles,doubles, trebles, zeros etc

Comment: Oh I see. I think using matrices might simplify some of the manual works. I'll come back to this after my A Levels end next week hahaha :)

Comment: Ok it will be good to see if we agree the answer. I did matrices at university but that was 40 years ago and I'm a bit rusty! Cheers

Comment: Good luck with your exams.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result. 9 scores are not possible.
163, 166, 169, 172, 173, 175, 176, 178 and 179.
Score with most combinations  is 60 (619 ways to score 60 points).

Anyone agree/disagree with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. There are 9 scores that cannot be achieved and they are in fact 163, 166, 169, 172, 173, 175, 175, 178, 179. I did this with python, here is my code:

```
possibleShotScore = []

for i in range(0, 21):
    possibleShotScore.append(i)
    possibleShotScore.append(i * 2)
    possibleShotScore.append(i * 3)

# Special cases:
possibleShotScore.append(25)
possibleShotScore.append(50)

# Only save unique scores:
possibleShotScore = set(possibleShotScore)


possibleFinalScores = []
for first in possibleShotScore:
    for second in possibleShotScore:
        for third in possibleShotScore:
            possibleFinalScores.append(first + second + third)
            # Uncomment following to see possible partitions for a number if present.
            # Here, I have it set to 149 but you can change this value to your liking.
            # if first + second + third == 149: print(first, second, third)

counter = 0
unattainablePartitions = []
for x in range(0, 181):
    if x not in possibleFinalScores:
        unattainablePartitions.append(x)
        counter += 1

print("No. of unattainable scores: ", counter)
print("Unattainable Scores: ", unattainablePartitions)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 dart.py 
No. of unattainable scores:  9
Unattainable Scores:  [163, 166, 169, 172, 173, 175, 176, 178, 179]
```